# Custom Page Wizard of Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, setup-project, setuptools

I have been working on custom pages on Inno Setup. I have the example code sample below, but when I run in on my Inno setup script editor, a compiler error pops up. It says: "Compiler error: Line 63: Column 3: Unknown identifier "authentication_form_CreatePage".
I cannot see any mistake. But there is one. If anyone can see it and knows about it, can you help me to cope with this please?

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "NewSampleSetup"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Example"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "BarChartExample2.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{8226770F-1270-434F-B53E-5539E78AD05B}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputDir=C:\Users\Intern1\Documents\Inno Setup Examples Output
OutputBaseFilename=Setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "                              {cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]  
Source: "C:\Users\stajyer1\Documents\Visual Studio               2012\Projects\BarChartExample2\BarChartExample2\bin\Debug\BarChartExample2.exe"; DestDir: "     {app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files



[Icons]
 Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
 Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks:       desktopicon

 [Run]
 Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,   {#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

 [CustomMessages]
 authentication_form_Caption=SQL Server Database Setup
 authentication_form_Description=Choose SQL Server database you will be using (ask your        administrator about its parameters)
 authentication_form_Label1_Caption0=Server Name:
 authentication_form_Label2_Caption0=Enter Path to SQL Server (e.g. .\SQLEXPRESS;    DEVSERVER)
 authentication_form_Label3_Caption0=User name:
 authentication_form_Label4_Caption0=Password:
 authentication_form_ServerNameEdit_Text0=-
 authentication_form_WindowsRadioButton_Caption0=Use Windows Authentication
 authentication_form_SqlRadioButton_Caption0=Use SQL Authentication
 authentication_form_UserEdit_Text0=-
 authentication_form_PasswordEdit_Text0=-

 [Code]
 procedure InitializeWizard();
 begin
 authentication_form_CreatePage(wpLicense);
 end;

 var
 Label1: TLabel;
 Label2: TLabel;
 Label3: TLabel;
 Label4: TLabel;
 ServerNameEdit: TEdit;
 WindowsRadioButton: TRadioButton;
 SqlRadioButton: TRadioButton;
 UserEdit: TEdit;
 PasswordEdit: TEdit;

 function authentication_form_CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
 var
 Page: TWizardPage;
 begin
 Page := CreateCustomPage(
 PreviousPageId,
 ExpandConstant('{cm:authentication_form_Caption}'),
 ExpandConstant('{cm:authentication_form_Description}')
 );
 Label1 := TLabel.Create(Page);
 with Label1 do
 begin
 Parent := Page.Surface;
 Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:authentication_form_Label1_Caption0}');
 Left := ScaleX(16);
 Top := ScaleY(0);
 Width := ScaleX(84);
 Height := ScaleY(17);
 end;

 Label2 := TLabel.Create(Page);
 with Label2 do
 begin
 Parent := Page.Surface;
 Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm: authentication_form_Label2_Caption0}');
 Left := ScaleX(16);
 Top := ScaleY(56);
 Width := ScaleX(300);
 Height := ScaleY(17);
 end;

 Label3 := TLabel.Create(Page);
 with Label3 do
 begin
 Parent := Page.Surface;
 Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm: authentication_form_Label3_Caption0}');
 Left := ScaleX(56);
 Top := ScaleY(136);
 Width := ScaleX(70);
 Height := ScaleY(17);
 end;

 Label4 := TLabel.Create(Page);
 with Label4 do
 begin
 Parent := Page.Surface;
 Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm: authentication_form_Label4_Caption0}');
 Left := ScaleX(56);
 Top := ScaleY(168);
 Width := ScaleX(63);
 Height := ScaleY(17);
 end;

 ServerNameEdit := TEdit.Create(Page);
 with ServerNameEdit do
 begin
 Parent := Page.Surface;
 Left := ScaleX(16);
 Top := ScaleY(24);
 Width := ScaleX(257);
 Height := ScaleY(25);
 TabOrder := 0;
 Text := ExpandConstant('{cm: authentication_form_ServerNameEdit_Text0}');
 end;

 WindowsRadioButton := TRadioButton.Create(Page);
 with WindowsRadioButton do
 begin
 Parent := Page.Surface;
 Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm: authentication_form_WindowsRadioButton_Caption0}');
 Left := ScaleX(16);
 Top := ScaleY(88);
 Width := ScaleX(225);
 Height := ScaleY(17);
 Checked := True;
 TabOrder := 1;
 TabStop := True;
 end;

 SqlRadioButton := TRadioButton.Create(Page);
 with SqlRadioButton do
 begin
 Parent := Page.Surface;
 Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm: authentication_form_SqlRadioButton_Caption0}');
 Left := ScaleX(16);
 Top := ScaleY(112);
 Width := ScaleX(193);
 Height := ScaleY(17);
 TabOrder := 2;
 end;

 UserEdit := TEdit.Create(Page);
 with UserEdit do
 begin
 Parent := Page.Surface;
 Left := ScaleX(136);
 Top := ScaleY(136);
 Width := ScaleX(121);
 Height := ScaleY(25);
 TabOrder := 3;
 Text := ExpandConstant('{cm: authentication_form_UserEdit_Text0}');
 end;

 PasswordEdit := TEdit.Create(Page);
 with PasswordEdit do
 begin
 Parent := Page.Surface;
 Left := ScaleX(136);
 Top := ScaleY(168);
 Width := ScaleX(121);
 Height := ScaleY(25);
 TabOrder := 4;
 PasswordChar := '*';
 Text := ExpandConstant('{cm: authentication_form_PasswordEdit_Text0}');
end;

with Page do
 begin
  OnNextButtonClick := @authentication_form_NextButtonClick;
 end;

Result := Page.ID;
end;

function authentication_form_NextButtonClick(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
 Result := True;
 if ServerNameEdit.Text <> ''   then
begin
   if SqlRadioButton.Checked then
   begin
      if UserEdit.Text = ''  then
      begin
         MsgBox('You should enter user name', mbError, MB_OK);
         Result := False;
      end
      else
      begin
        if PasswordEdit.Text = '' then
        begin
           MsgBox('You should enter password', mbError, MB_OK);
           Result := False;
        end
      end
   end
end
else
begin
MsgBox('You should enter path to SQL Server Database', mbError, MB_OK);
Result := False;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "NewSampleSetup"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Example"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "BarChartExample2.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{8226770F-1270-434F-B53E-5539E78AD05B}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputDir=C:\Users\sandaa\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=Setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "                              {cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]  
;Source: "C:\Users\stajyer1\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BarChartExample2\BarChartExample2\bin\Debug\BarChartExample2.exe"; DestDir: "     {app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files



[Icons]
 Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
 Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks:       desktopicon

 [Run]
 Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,   {#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent


[Code]
var

    FirstLabel: TLabel;
    SecondLabel: TLabel;
    ThirdLabel: TLabel;
    FourthLabel: TLabel;
    ServerNameTextBox: TEdit;
    WindowsRadioButton: TRadioButton;
    SQLRadioButton: TRadioButton;
    txtUserName: TEdit;
    txtPassword: TEdit;


function AuthenticateDataPage(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
    Result :=True;
    if ServerNameTextBox.Text <> '' then
    begin
        if SQLRadioButton.Checked then
            begin
                if txtUserName.Text =''  then
                    begin
                        MsgBox('You should enter user name', mbError, MB_OK);
                            Result :=False;
                        end
                    else
                        begin
                            if txtPassword.Text ='' then
                                begin
                                    MsgBox('You should enter password', mbError, MB_OK);
                                    Result :=False;
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            else
            begin
                MsgBox('You should enter path to SQL Server Database', mbError, MB_OK);
                Result :=False;
    end;
end;


function CreateDataPage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
var
    Page: TWizardPage;
begin
    Page :=CreateCustomPage(PreviousPageId,'SQL Server Database Setup',
    'Choose SQL Server database you will be using (ask your administrator about its parameters');

    FirstLabel :=TLabel.Create(Page);
    with FirstLabel do
    begin
        Parent :=Page.Surface;
        Caption :='Server Name';
        Left :=ScaleX(16);
        Top :=ScaleY(0);
        Width :=ScaleX(84);
        Height :=ScaleY(17);
    end;

    SecondLabel :=TLabel.Create(Page);
    With SecondLabel Do
    begin
        Parent :=Page.Surface;
        Caption :='Enter Path to SQL Server (e.g. .\SQLEXPRESS; DEVSERVER)';
        Left :=ScaleX(16);
        Top :=ScaleY(56);
        Width :=ScaleX(300);
        Height :=ScaleY(17);
    end;

    ThirdLabel :=TLabel.Create(Page);
    with ThirdLabel do
        begin
            Parent :=Page.Surface;
            Caption :='User name';
            Left :=ScaleX(56);
            Top :=ScaleY(136);
            Width :=ScaleX(70);
            Height :=ScaleY(17);
        end;

    FourthLabel :=TLabel.Create(Page);
    with FourthLabel do
    begin
            Parent :=Page.Surface;
            Caption :='Password';
            Left :=ScaleX(56);
            Top :=ScaleY(168);
            Width :=ScaleX(63);
            Height :=ScaleY(17);
    end;

    ServerNameTextBox :=TEdit.Create(Page);
    with ServerNameTextBox do
    begin
            Parent :=Page.Surface;
            Left :=ScaleX(16);
            Top :=ScaleY(24);
            Width :=ScaleX(257);
            Height :=ScaleY(25);
            TabOrder :=0;
            Text :='';
    end;


    WindowsRadioButton :=TRadioButton.Create(Page);
    with WindowsRadioButton do
    begin
        Parent :=Page.Surface;
        Caption :='Use Windows Authentication';
        Left :=ScaleX(16);
        Top :=ScaleY(88);
        Width :=ScaleX(225);
        Height :=ScaleY(17);
        Checked :=True;
        TabOrder :=1;
        TabStop :=True;
    end;

    SQLRadioButton :=TRadioButton.Create(Page);
    with SQLRadioButton do
        begin
        Parent :=Page.Surface;
        Caption :='Use SQL Authentication';
        Left :=ScaleX(16);
        Top :=ScaleY(112);
        Width :=ScaleX(193);
        Height :=ScaleY(17);
        TabOrder :=2;
    end;


    txtUserName :=TEdit.Create(Page);
    with txtUserName do
    begin
        Parent :=Page.Surface;
        Left :=ScaleX(136);
        Top :=ScaleY(136);
        Width :=ScaleX(121);
        Height :=ScaleY(25);
        TabOrder :=3;
        Text :='';
    end;

    txtPassword :=TEdit.Create(Page);
    with txtPassword do
    begin
        Parent :=Page.Surface;
        Left :=ScaleX(136);
        Top :=ScaleY(168);
        Width :=ScaleX(121);
        Height :=ScaleY(25);
        TabOrder :=4;
        PasswordChar :='*';
        Text :='';
    end;


    with Page do
    begin
        OnNextButtonClick :=@AuthenticateDataPage;
    end;

    Result :=Page.ID;

end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    CreateDataPage(wpLicense);
end;
```

The only thing I left out is the custommessages.

Comment: I think it is about the scope of Pascal script. It has static scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward-declare a method, like `authentication_form_CreatePage` if you don't like to reorder your methods:

```
//forward declaration
function authentication_form_CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer; forward;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
     //the method is known to the compiler, even before he looked into it
     authentication_form_CreatePage(wpLicense);
end;

function authentication_form_CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
begin
    ... actual implementation ...
end;
```